# Control sub form from another thread c#

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker, multithreading

In my project, I have:
Form1, <-- this is the main form, run in main thread
Form2, <-- this is the subform
1 background worker

experienced problem:
when I create a new form inside background worker, and show it using

```
Form2 test = new Form2(); *test.show();*
```

the form shows up, but freezed and I can do nothing to the form

the question is:
1. is it able to create a form inside a background worker but, the form will run on the main thread?
2. if yes, how to do it? :)
3. if not, how to control a form that, I declared on the main thread, from backgroundworker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Control.Invoke to create new Form's .

```
public static class InvokeControl
    {
        public static void InvokeIfRequired(this Control c, Action<Control> action)
        {
            if (c.InvokeRequired)
            {
                c.Invoke(new Action(() => action(c)));
            }
            else
            {
                action(c);
            }
        }
    }
```

and class this method by

```
InvokeControl.InvokeIfRequired(this, c => {//Create you're form here});
```

Comment: I'm new to c# and kinda confused about invoke and how it should work. where should I place the InvokeControl class? is it editable?

Comment: @ch0eb1t you can Place wherever you want InvokeControl Class ,and you should call it's Method InvokeIfRequired() with the Example above into BackGroundWorker-RunWorkerAsync Event

Comment: It would be good to explain why this is, not just say "do this." The reason is that UI should only be handled in the main thread. If you create forms in other threads, they will not have event loops running, so they will not get any Windows events and will freeze. And if you will try to access UI components from other threads, there may be race conditions, thread-local storage issues and whatnot. This is why it is not allowed.